# Question about building apache httpd with cl compiler on windows?

Tags: apache, cl

I'm in the process of setting up my environment for a 1-day learning project. I want to build Apache's httpd version 2.4.51 in an x86_64 Windows 11 environment. I've tried various things and looked around, but quickly grasping a large project and building it the way I want has proven to be challenging. Seeking assistance.

1. I want to build version 2.4.51 of httpd.
2. I want to build it using the cl compiler with the ability to set optimization options as I wish.
3. I want to use a module called mod_lua.
   Please help.

When I attempted it in a Linux environment, I succeeded in building it. For example, I needed to install apr, so I did and resolved the necessary dependencies, but the build didn't work. After reading the documentation, I succeeded in building it by downloading the official tarball. However, Windows is challenging due to a lack of references.